# mysql api submite towice

Tags: php, mysql, api

I tried many times to submit the form when it submitted it repeated the submission twice on the data. I don't understand why,please help me. and when I put the header location it doesn't work ever
here is the code

```
<?php
  $name= $_POST['form_name']; 
    $mrn= $_POST['form_mrn']; 
    $mobile= $_POST['form_mobile'];
$link = mysql_connect('server', 'user', 'password'); 
if (!$link) { 
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error()); 
} 
$db_selected = mysql_select_db('dbname');
if (!$db_selected) {
    die('Could not select database: ' . mysql_error());
}
mysql_set_charset('utf8',$link); 
$query = "INSERT INTO pharmacy ( name , mrn , mobile  ) VALUES  ('$name', '$mrn', '$mobile')"; 
$result = mysql_query($query);
header('Location: form.html');  
$link->close();
?>
```

Comment: provide your html code...

Comment: try with `exit` after header.

Comment: i tried the exit it doesn't work

Comment: **WARNING**: If you're just learning PHP, please, do not use the [`mysql_query`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) interface. It’s so awful and dangerous that it was removed in PHP 7. A replacement like [PDO is not hard to learn](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/) and a guide like [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) explains best practices. Your user parameters are **not** [properly escaped](http://bobby-tables.com/php) and there are [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/) that can be exploited.

Comment: There's no way this code works. `$link->close()` looks like it was ripped from some `mysqli` code, the rest is from something dredged up from the 1990s. These calls are not compatible. Where did you learn to code this way? You need a better reference than whatever you're working from because this is really confused. If you're learning, that's fine, but you need to follow better examples.

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/ I used this to learn, I tried the other PHP code it doesn't work with my

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
   <?php   
        $name= $_POST['form_name']; 
        $mrn= $_POST['form_mrn']; 
        $mobile= $_POST['form_mobile'];
        $link = mysql_connect('server', 'user', 'password'); 
     if (!$link) { 
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error()); 
 } 
$db_selected = mysql_select_db('dbname');
if (!$db_selected) {
die('Could not select database: ' . mysql_error());
}
mysql_set_charset('utf8',$link);
```

//Just Put this code before inserting

```
 if($name !=""){ 
$query = "INSERT INTO pharmacy ( name , mrn , mobile  ) VALUES  ('$name','$mrn', '$mobile')"; 
$result = mysql_query($query);
header('Location: form.html');  
}
$link->close();
?>
```

Just check condition before insert. Let me know if facing same issue.

Comment: I would discourage this approach. OP should rewrite.